# VirtualBox giving Secure Boot error - Despite the fact it's not installed?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, log, secure-boot, syslog

My /var/log/syslog file kept getting tremendously big, I checked the last few lines with tail and I found this

```
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: The Secure Boot key you've entered is not valid. The password used must be
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: between 8 and 16 characters.
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will be asked again after a reboot.
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: Enter the same password again to verify you have typed it correctly.
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: Invalid password
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: The Secure Boot key you've entered is not valid. The password used must be
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: between 8 and 16 characters.
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will be asked again after a reboot.
Jun 16 19:21:18 Freedom-MAX-G0101 vboxdrv.sh[7974]: Enter the same password again to verify you have typed it correctly.
```

So, seeing that it's an error about VirtualBox, I decided to uninstall it. But when I tried to do it with apt-get remove it said it's not installed?

```
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete «virtualbox» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 140 no actualizados.
1 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se utilizarán 0 B de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Configurando v4l2loopback-dkms (0.12.3-1ubuntu0.4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete v4l2loopback-dkms (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete v4l2loopback-dkms script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 v4l2loopback-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

(I apologize for the fact that it's in spanish, I have it set as my main system language)

Now, how can I make sure that VirtualBox stops filling my log files?

Comment: Please add `dkms status` and `dpkg -l | grep dkms` to your question. Also `uname -r`